# manim copy and property propagation (rectangle grid_xstep)

Tags: python, manim

I'm starting with manim (`Manim Community v0.17.1`) and I got behaviors that I can't explain on some very basic example, any help appreciated.

```py
class SquareScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        kwargs = {"fill_opacity": 1, "stroke_color": WHITE}

        square1 = Square(5, color=RED, grid_xstep=1, grid_ystep=1, **kwargs)
        square2 = square1.copy().set(color=BLUE, **kwargs).shift(UP + RIGHT)

        self.add(square2, square1)
```

- `square1` is displayed without a grid, I don't know why
- `square2` does have a grid

EDIT: I managed to solve the problem by setting `fill_color=RED` instead of `color=RED`. As I noticed the grid was there but also `RED` hence not visible.

Still it doesn't explain why the `BLUE` square grid color was `WHITE` then..

[image: rectangles]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how `Square` processes `grid_xstep` and `grid_ystep` (see https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/9efe81daa3e88e25244affd3700e2d2a8b527635/manim/mobject/geometry/polygram.py#L552-L581), I would actually consider this behavior a bug: the method *only* passes the `color` keyword argument to the constructed `Line` objects.

The construction of the lines also happens right at the end of the constructor; the color / fill color / stroke color of the parent mobject, the `Square`, have already been set at that point. Setting them (again) after the mobject has been constructed then also properly handles the color of the grid lines.

Feel free to open a bug report over at https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim!

Comment: Thanks, I opened one [`Issue #3082`](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/issues/3082)